# What do the : and ' operators mean

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have to make modifications to an Oracle stored procedure that has the following lines.

```
      InsStmt = 'INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (Emp_cd, Emp_lst_nm, Emp_fst,nm) VALUES
                (:Emp_cd, :Emp_lst_nm, :Emp_fst_nm);';
    varExec :='
    DECLARE
      var1 VARCHAR2(100);
    BEGIN
      var1 := :Emp_cd||:Emp_lst_nm||:Emp_fst_nm;
      '||InsStmt||'
    END;';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varExec USING ip_param_cd, ip_param_lnm, ip_param_fnm;
```

I have only basic understanding of Oracle stored procedures. After some research I found out that the || operator is for concatenating strings.

But I'm still wondering what does the below statement mean

```
var1 := :Emp_cd||:Emp_lst_nm||:Emp_fst_nm;
      '||InsStmt||'
```

I went through the tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm#CIHGDECD but could not find any help.

Comment: this is an extract from a bigger picture, we need the whole code.

Comment: updated with full code

Comment: This is a nonsensical piece of code.  There's no point asking us to guess at the intentions of the author.  All you can do is ask them, or whoever tasked you with changing it.  The VAR1 assignment is pointless as it isn't (apparently) used anywhere.  Perhaps it is intended for auditing or debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of the trigger context, the column `:` is used to bind variables within a statement.

For example:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE mytable SET age = 25 WHERE age = :1' 
     USING IN localVarAge;
```

In this case, the `:1` value would be replaced by the value of `localVarAge`.
The order the ':' variables appear in the prepared statement matter, not their actual labels.

In your code there's clearly a piece missing, this part `var1 := :Emp_cd||:Emp_lst_nm||:Emp_fst_nm;` should be within quotes. That would make sense anyway since you have right after that a closing quote and a concatenation.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. Actually they are creating a dynamic procedure statement and executing it. Still dont understand what is the use of var1;

Comment: oh, I think they don't use it! Probably a left over of a past code... For instance for dbms_outputting before inserting

Comment: I think we can tune that procedure, you should open another question with the whole code for performances optimization i think this is not optimal right now